# change only onclicked content and reset the rest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Sound Track List Image URL:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gtd4hrhfhxl4sm/song2.png?dl=0

I have list of sound track. If i click on the first song Play button will appear as well as click second one the play button should be moved to second song and first should be as usual. But output is not an expected result. Can anyone please guide me.??

**My script is here**

```
function loadSong(song_url, play_img, sequence_id){
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "images/play.jpg");
    document.getElementById(sequence_id).appendChild(x);
}
```

Comment: please post some html code as well

Comment: <td >
<span class="okay" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" /> <?php echo $i; ?></span>
<span class="showme" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" /> 
<img src="images/play.jpg"></span></td>
                        
<td onclick="loadSong('<?php echo $song_url; ?>', '<?php echo $music_res['id']; ?>', <?php echo $i; ?>)" 
id="<?php echo $music_res['id'];?>" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Click to Play"><?php echo trim($song_name); ?></td>

<td ><?php echo trim($artist_name); ?></td>

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the HTML structure, I'll assume it's something like:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="song">
        <div class="songImgDiv"></div>
        <div class="songTitle">Song 1</div>
    </div>
    <!-- other songs -->
</div>
```

And the `img` has class `.activePlay`.

```
$('.song').on('click', function () {
    var imgSrc = "images/play.jpg";
    $('.song img.activePlay').remove();
    var img = $('<img/>').prop('src', imgSrc).addClass('activePlay');
    $(this).find('.songImgDiv').append(img);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/uyk8yro5/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much @samurai... let me check with my code. :)